# Getting rid of StaleStateException in spring-boot hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, session, exception, spring-boot

I have gone through [this](http://www.jroller.com/maximdim/entry/hibernate_batch_update_returned_unexpected) post. Reading this post I realised I was getting this exception because of object persistence across sessions and that I had to delete the object from the session first before deleting actually using the DAO.

How do I get the session in Spring boot so that I can delete the object from the Session first before actually deleting it using the DAO?

I have tried adding this to the configuration class:

```
@Bean
public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
}
```

and getting this session using

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

and then finally using the session:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.delete(myEntity);
myDao.delete(myEntity);
```

But then I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:695)
```

Comment: Where do you configure the db access? This might perhaps help you: https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate though it uses JPA. Is there a reason you want to access Hibernate session directly?